# Pass PHP array into JS

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I want to make a memory game but I don't know how to pass a value of an array from PHP into JS.

I need to pass some number into a JS variable but only get the first number of the table when the user clicks.

The numbers already exist inside inside a PHP array but I need to pass the number clicked in a JS variable

PHP code (to get numbers random):

```
$numbers = range(0, 9);
shuffle($numbers);
```

HTML and PHP code (Table):

```
<table width="200" border="1" id="tabla" style="visibility:visible" >
<tr>
<?php foreach($numbers as $key){ ?>
<td ><a href="#" onclick="validacion()" style="color:#000; text- decoration:none;"> <div class="container"> <h1 class="box" id="text"> <?php  echo $key; ?> </h1> </div> </a></td>
<?php } ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

JS code (Can I get ONLY the first number in the table?)

```
function validacion(){
var text=document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;
alert(text);
}
```

When I click on any number of the table I get the same first number. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

IDs have to be unique, you can't have `id="text"` on every row of the table. `document.getElementById("text")` will always return the first element with that ID, not the one in the row the user clicks on.

Use `class="text"` instead. Then change your function to look for the element with that class in the current element. The HTML needs to pass the element to the validation function:

```
<a href="#" onclick="validacion(this)" style="color:#000; text- decoration:none;">
```

Then the JS will be:

```
function validacion(elem) {
    var text = elem.getElementsByClassName("text")[0].innerHTML;
    alert(text);
}
```

Note also that putting a `DIV` inside an `A` is not valid in HTML 4.01. See [Is putting a div inside an anchor ever correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct)

Here's the full code:

```js
function validacion(elem) {
  var text = elem.getElementsByClassName("text")[0].innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" onclick="validacion(this)" style="color:#000; text- decoration:none;">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="box text" > 1 </h1> 
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" onclick="validacion(this)" style="color:#000; text- decoration:none;">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="box text" > 2 </h1> 
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" onclick="validacion(this)" style="color:#000; text- decoration:none;">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="box text" > 3 </h1> 
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
Alert here:
<div id="alert"><div>
```

Comment: thanks for reply but this function getElementsByClassName no exist

Comment: It works for me, I've added a working example.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that..

```
<?php foreach($numbers as $key){ ?>
<td ><a href="#" onclick="validacion()" style="color:#000; text- decoration:none;"> <div class="container"> <h1 class="box" id="text"> <?php  echo $key; ?> </h1> </div> </a></td>
<?php } ?>
```

instead

```
<?php foreach($numbers as $key){
 echo '<td ><a href="#" onc...';
}?>
```

another thing,

```
function validacion(id){
var text=document.getElementById('text'+id).innerHTML;
alert(text);
}
```

and add the ID to the ID in the foreach loop : id=\'"text"+id\'